# Swift Firebase RealtimeDatabase doesn't give child specific data with tons of data

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my project I used to have more than 6.000 points of interest (pois). Now I need to access for example the *title* of one poi with specific ID. Normally it works fine in my app when I need some specific from user for example.

I do the same steps like I usually do. But when I try to access poi data, it only give the whole "poi" data (>6.000 pois). I tried getData even observeSingeEvent.

This is my database structure:

```
{
  "pois" : {
    "0015CF32-D5B2-481A-8DA2-877E621A4E82" : {
      city = a,
      "country" = a,
      creator = System,
      id = "0015CF32-D5B2-481A-8DA2-877E621A4E82",
      latitude = "1",
      longitude = "1",
      street = "a",
      title = "a",        
      type = 0,
      zip = 1
    }, + 6.000 more...
  "users" : {
    "6EA555FA-BAA8-4EDE-BD05-5D290B953CAC" : {
      "City" : "Motown",
      "Country" : "Anywhere",
      "Forename" : "Fred",
      "Surename" : "Feuerstein",
      "onTour" : "false",
      "registeredEmail" : "fred@feuerstein.com",
      "userId" : "6EA555FA-BAA8-4EDE-BD05-5D290B953CAC",
      "userImagePath" : "6EA555FA-BAA8-4EDE-BD05-5D290B953CAC.jpg",
      "username" : "Tom"
    }
  }
}
```

My request and result for user data: *(I reduced the whole code because it doesn't matter what happens within the completion)*

```
database.child("users/6EA555FA-BAA8-4EDE-BD05-5D290B953CAC/registeredEmail").getData { error, snap in
  print(snap)
}

results: Snap (registeredEmail) fred@feuerstein.com
```

My request and result for user data.

```
database.child("pois/42E11715-B3B0-46D9-A568-E578870EF9A4/title/").getData { error, snap in
  print(snap)
}

results (Shorten):
Snap (title) {
    "0015CF32-D5B2-481A-8DA2-877E621A4E82" =     {
        city = a;
        "country" = a;
        creator = System;
        id = "0015CF32-D5B2-481A-8DA2-877E621A4E82";
        latitude = "1";
        longitude = "1";
        street = "a";
        title = "a";
        type = 0;
        zip = 1;
    };
    "002A3A1C-DE5C-4CB4-AD36-1B4495B77F22" =     {
        city = "b";
        "country" = b;
        creator = System;
        id = "002A3A1C-DE5C-4CB4-AD36-1B4495B77F22";
        latitude = "1";
        longitude = "1";
        rating = 0;
        street = "b";
        title = "b";
        type = 0;
        zip = 1;
    }; + 6.000 more pois
```

I guess this coherent with the amount of data in "pois". Someone an idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: Hmm... that second result looks unexpected. Can you try using `observeSingleEvent(of: .value` instead of `getData`, just to see if this is a problem/bug in `getData`?

Comment: Thank you. I tried it with observe before and failed. But today I tried it again and no it works as it should!

`database.child("pois/42E11715-B3B0-46D9-A568-E578870EF9A4/title").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snap in
            print(snap)
        }`

Results: `Snap (title) Restaurant Zum Parkhaus`